# OrientDB recovery after ungraceful shutdown

Tags: orientdb

When OrientDB is shutdown ungracefully by someone power cycling the box, OrientDB ends up in a state where data restore fails. Are there any recommendations on how to gracefully recover from such ungraceful shutdown? We are looking for ways that the system can recover by itself during a power outage.

Generic output, as may have seen by many.

```
<DATE> WARNING {db=TestDb} segment file 'database.ocf' was not closed correctly last time [OSingleFileSegment]
<DATE> WARNING {db=TestDb} Storage TestDb was not closed properly. Will try to restore from write ahead log. [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
<DATE> INFO  {db=TestDb} Looking for last checkpoint... [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
<DATE> INFO  {db=TestDb} FULL checkpoint found. [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
<DATE> INFO  {db=TestDb} Data restore procedure from full checkpoint is started. Restore is performed from LSN OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=322830} [OLocalPaginatedStorage]

Record com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OCheckpointEndRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=322854}} will be skipped during data restore. [OLocalPaginatedStorage]{db=TestDb} Exception during storage data restore.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 33
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OAtomicUnitEndRecord.fromStream(OAtomicUnitEndRecord.java:59)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OWALRecordsFactory.fromStream(OWALRecordsFactory.java:121)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.ODiskWriteAheadLog.read(ODiskWriteAheadLog.java:1009)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.restoreFrom(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:2261)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.restoreFromFullCheckPoint(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:2231)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.restoreFromCheckPoint(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:2220)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.restoreFromWAL(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:2171)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.restoreIfNeeded(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1493)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.open(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:154)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.open(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:223)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.openDatabase(OServer.java:631)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.openDatabase(OServer.java:613)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.command.OServerCommandAuthenticatedDbAbstract.authenticate(OServerCommandAuthenticatedDbAbstract.java:167)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.command.OServerCommandAuthenticatedDbAbstract.beforeExecute(OServerCommandAuthenticatedDbAbstract.java:127)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.command.get.OServerCommandGetConnect.beforeExecute(OServerCommandGetConnect.java:50)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.service(ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.java:171)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.execute(ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.java:574)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:69)

<DATE> SEVERE {db=TestDb} Internal server error:
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot open local storage '<location>/orientdb-enterprise-2.1-rc1/databases/TestDb' with mode=rw
```

Comment: Looks like this is fixed in 2.0.10.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Nexus 3.10 (internally using OrientDB 2.2.X) , but apparently the DB is now able to gracefully recover, I get a warning the first time I connect, but the second time it's cleaned:

```
[centos@localhost nexus-3.10.0-04]$ java -jar lib/support/nexus-orient-console.jar 

OrientDB console v.2.2.31 (build 285537d2767275f460df32c6a3be01bfff6a517c, branch 2.2.x) https://www.orientdb.com
Type 'help' to display all the supported commands.
orientdb> connect plocal:/home/centos/nexus310/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/component admin admin

Connecting to database [plocal:/home/centos/nexus310/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/component] with user 'admin'...
2018-10-16 15:26:59:037 WARNI {db=component} Storage 'component' was not closed properly. Will try to recover from write ahead log...
2018-10-16 15:26:59:042 WARNI {db=component} Record com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointEndRecord{lsn=LSN{segment=61, position=2073}} will be skipped during data restore
2018-10-16 15:26:59:043 WARNI {db=component} Record OFuzzyCheckpointStartRecord{lsn=LSN{segment=61, position=2080}} com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointStartRecord{lsn=null, previousCheckpoint=LSN{segment=61, position=2033}} will be skipped during data restore
2018-10-16 15:26:59:043 WARNI {db=component} Record com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointEndRecord{lsn=LSN{segment=61, position=2120}} will be skipped during data restoreOK
orientdb {db=component}> exit

[centos@localhost nexus-3.10.0-04]$ java -jar lib/support/nexus-orient-console.jar 

OrientDB console v.2.2.31 (build 285537d2767275f460df32c6a3be01bfff6a517c, branch 2.2.x) https://www.orientdb.com
Type 'help' to display all the supported commands.
orientdb> connect plocal:/home/centos/nexus310/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/component admin admin

Connecting to database [plocal:/home/centos/nexus310/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/component] with user 'admin'...OK
orientdb {db=component}>
```